# Does a static variable in Spring Rest API Controller will cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, spring, memory, log4j

Ok so our team is developing apis with Spring Framework, and after several additional features, we face a memory leak and decided to recheck the entire code to find the cause of the leak.

Now I'm curious about one particular practice we are doing here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class TransactionController {
    final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TransactionController.class);
    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create-transaction", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    String createTransaction(@RequestBody String json, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
           ...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(LogAdapter.logToLog4jException(startTime, request, "", json, gson.toJson("output here"), ex.toString()), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So will those two static variables will be recreated every single api call in this class? Or it's better to declare and use them locally instead?

Edit:
that static logger and gson variables exist in every of our controller classes

Thanks before

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak?
And why not use dependency injection?
That is what Spring does best... So remove the static keyword and create a `Bean` of your needed class.

Comment: So the first time i noticed this is when i use a monitor (i used Visual VM), and i realized that the heap memory is raising until 4-6gb after 3 days of server restart, that time i was wondering, does the garbage collector actually able to collect something?

Then i'm trying to learn the causes of memory leak in Java, and overused of static variable is one of it, now i just want to make sure of myself about this in this very context because this piece of code is literally everywhere in our project

Comment: The logger won't be an issue, the `Gson` could be, just use a single instance and inject it. But it is more likely that the cause is somewhere else. The use of `static` can be an issue but only if it holds other references preventing GC runs or when using an app server a (re)deployment of the app. In this case that isn't an issue so which is why it is highly unlikely that this is the issue.